# Altimetric image with blank space when merging

Tags: qgis, raster, mapping, rasterization, gdal-merge

I have downloaded some tiff images that has altimetric data from the Brazilian [SRTM website](https://www.cnpm.embrapa.br/projetos/relevobr/download/ro/ro.htm): where i am using raster layers to apply merging. However, i have some problems with my merged images, a portion of my map is blank:

[image]

These areas correspond to regions: SC-20-zc, SD-20-XA, SC-20-Z-D, SD-20-X-B, SD-20-X-C, SD-20-X-D.

However when i plot them inside the state/province limits just using the raster added layers, they show up just fine, why is this happening?
I've tried visualizing the raster layers of that area that has bright color/blank space and this is the output:

[image]

This is my hypsometric map:

[image]

The light blue area is just missing, is this something wrong with how i performed the merging?

This is the actual map where apparently it's the yellow zone that represents the texture portion is blank in my map:

[image]

I'd like to know, what did i do wrong and how do i fix it?